# where are static blocks used, and what potential values in eav_attribute

Tags: static-block, magento-1.4, architecture

I am about 3 months into Magento at this point.  I have worked with static blocks `core_blocks` being used in a store for categories to either supplement or replace the category list.  I know these are referenced in table `eav_attribute` as value='landing_page'.

I would like to find out our "orphaned" static blocks.  Where else can static blocks be used, and what are the possible values in the eav tables that would identify them?

Comment: Did you tag this question correctly? Magento v1.4?

Comment: yes - this is the version we are using.  Perhaps you could share any difference later versions use blocks for as well, of course.

Comment: I was just surprised as 1.4 is quite old and VERY buggy. There are multiple high-priority security fixes in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no final answer to this, static blocks can be included in many different ways.

#### Core features

- Static blocks can be included in the CMS, using a widget directive: Search for `widget type="cms/widget_block"` in `cms_page.content` and `cms_block.content`
- Static blocks can be added as widget instances. Search for widget instances with the type "CMS Static Block":
      [image: screenshot widget instances]

  (or in the database: `select * from widget_instance where instance_type='cms/widget_block'`)
- Static blocks can be added with layout XML like this:

  ```
  <block type="cms/block" name="foobar">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>the_block_id</block_id></action>
   </block>
  ```

  Search for `<action method="setBlockId">` in  `catalog_product_entity_text` and `catalog_category_entity_text`. There are several attributes that contain layout XML updates.

#### Extension/Theme features

- Extensions could add their own EAV attributes that refer to a static block, similar to `landing_page`, or configuration values (in the `core_config_data` table). Search for `'cms/block'` in `app/code/community` and `app/code/local` to find out where static blocks are used.
- Also search in `app/design`, there might be hard coded includes.
- There might be WYSIWYG attributes with widgets enabled, so search for `widget type="cms/widget_block"` in `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_category_entity_text` and `eav_entity_text`.
- Search for `<action method="setBlockId">` in `app/design/frontend` to find blocks added via layout XML in the theme.

Comment: Good works... :)